# Error while retrieving image from SQL server 2008 using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to retrieve image from SQL server using C#, by clicking SHOW button in Windows form and display it in PictureBox of the Windows Form (in Visual Studio 2010). The code below is giving error “out of memory”. On using debugger, it is observed that barrImg gets the correct values, but still it is not displaying the image.

```
namespace try1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection conS;
    SqlCommand cmdS;
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapS;
    string constr = "Data Source=______,_____;Network Library=__________;Initial Catalog=___________;User Id=___________;Password=__________";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "select col1 from table1 where condition1";
        conS = new SqlConnection(constr);
        try
        {
            byte[] outbyte_LP1 = null;
            DataSet gD = new DataSet();
            conS.Open();
            cmdS = new SqlCommand(sql, conS);
            dataadapS = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdS);
            dataadapS.Fill(gD, "gd");
            if (gD.Tables["gd"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                //FileStream FS = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.Create);
                //byte[] blob = (byte[])gD.Tables["gd"].Rows[0]["col1"];
                //FS.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                //FS.Close();
                //FS = null;
                //pctimg1.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);
                //byte[] barrImg = (byte[])cmdS.ExecuteScalar();
                //string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                //FileStream fs = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                //fs.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
                //fs.Flush();
                //fs.Close();
                //pctimg1.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);

                DateTime actDate = (DateTime)gD.Tables["gd"].Rows[0]["DateTime"];
                outbyte_LP1 = (byte[])gD.Tables["gd"].Rows[0]["col1"];
                MemoryStream ms_LP1 = new MemoryStream(outbyte_LP1, 0, outbyte_LP1.Length);
                ms_LP1.Write(outbyte_LP1, 0, outbyte_LP1.Length);

                pctimg1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms_LP1, true);

            }}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }}

    private void btn_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (conS.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conS.Close();}
        this.Close();}}}
```

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? does it fail every time? or just on repeated attempts?

Comment: Debugger runs throughout the try, and then it jumps to catch where it shows 'out of memory'. It fails every time.

Comment: Ok so which line was it on before it jumps?

Comment: On this line:pctimg1.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);

Comment: I tried using MemoryStream as well, but it gives the same error.

outbyte_LP1 = (byte[])gD.Tables["gd"].Rows[0]["LP_T"];
                    MemoryStream ms_LP1 = new MemoryStream(outbyte_LP1, 0, outbyte_LP1.Length);
                    ms_LP1.Write(outbyte_LP1, 0, outbyte_LP1.Length);
                   
                    pctimg1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms_LP1, true);

Comment: you know your code is missing a } .. it maybe helpful if you post more of your actual code and not cut out chunks

Comment: Alright. Let me edit few stuffs.

Comment: Edited. It includes everything.

Comment: What happens if instead of writing it to the Image you use it in a Bitmap which you then assign to the image?

Comment: "Out of memory" is `System.Drawing`s "I give up, I don't know what happened" message. It could be literally anything. Please try to create a [mcve] - one that starts with an image file, *round-trips* it through a DB table and then tries to load it. We shouldn't need any UI bits. For all we know, the issue is in how the image is being *stored*.

Comment: Problem is while displaying the image. Since, the byte array has correct output. So, the conversion of byte array to image has some issue. It would  be helpful, if you try once.

Comment: On checking the DB, image stored has size of 16, which means it is reference to the stored image.

Comment: @BugFinder, When using Bitmap, it says, 'Parameter is not valid'.